# Remove start and end of BASE64 string JAVA

Tags: java, regex, base64

How can i remove, in java, the basic information appended to a BASE64 string. I receive xml where an element contains a BASE64 picture but in the start of the string I got the following content:

```
<![CDATA[Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

begin-base64 644 Billede installation_2818.jpg
```

and in the end of the string i have the closing trails:

```
]]>
```

I have tried to get the conent into a java String type and call replace with some regex expressions like

```
".*.jpg"
```

But is does not work, I think it is because it is too large the picture, but I am not sure, I have run out of ideas. I even made a small test program like this one:

```
public class Base64RegExExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String xml = "<![CDATA[Content-type: image/jpeg Content-transfer-encoding: base-64begin-base64 644 Billede installation_2818.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]]>";

    xml = xml.replaceFirst(".*\\.jpg","").replaceFirst("]]>", "");
    xml = xml.replaceFirst("]]>", "");
    /*byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageData);
    System.out.println(new String(bytes));*/
}
```

}

Just to test regex expressions, and with this I can remove the unneeded parts of the string. Can it be that in the orginal string there are some newlines that I have to account for in the regex?

If i get the following input:

```
<![CDATA[Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

begin-base64 644 Billede installation_2818.jpg
/9j/4QtCRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAIAoAAAEBBAABAAAAmAcAAA8BAgAIAAAAngAA
ABABAgAJAAAApgAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAsAAAABsBBQABAAAAuAAAACgBAwABAAAA
AgAAADEBAgAOAAAAwAAAADIBAgAUAAAAzgAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA4gAAAHwDAABT
QU1TVU5HAFNNLUczODhGAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAAARzM4OEZYWFUxQU9IMwAyMDE1OjExOjE4
IDEyOjI4OjIzACIAmoIFAAEAAACAAgAAnYIFAAEAAACIAgAAIogDAAEAAAACAAAAJ4gDAAEAAAC0
AAAAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIwA5ACABQAAACQAgAABJACABQAAACkAgAAAZEHAAQAAAABAgMAAZIKAAEA...]]>
```

I would like to endup with just this part of the input:

```
/9j/4QtCRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAIAoAAAEBBAABAAAAmAcAAA8BAgAIAAAAngAA
ABABAgAJAAAApgAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAsAAAABsBBQABAAAAuAAAACgBAwABAAAA
AgAAADEBAgAOAAAAwAAAADIBAgAUAAAAzgAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA4gAAAHwDAABT
QU1TVU5HAFNNLUczODhGAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAAARzM4OEZYWFUxQU9IMwAyMDE1OjExOjE4
IDEyOjI4OjIzACIAmoIFAAEAAACAAgAAnYIFAAEAAACIAgAAIogDAAEAAAACAAAAJ4gDAAEAAAC0
AAAAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIwA5ACABQAAACQAgAABJACABQAAACkAgAAAZEHAAQAAAABAgMAAZIKAAEA...
```

Comment: Add the DOTALL modifer to the 1st regex: `.replaceFirst("(?s).*?\\.jpg","")`

Comment: It would also help your question if you show us the exact string with which you want to end up.

Comment: exactly which string you want to remove from the whole string specify it clearly so we can understand properly.